# how to make xdo for time AM/PM in lowercase in rtf file template <?format-date:xdoxslt:sysdate_as_xsdformat();'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'?>

Tags: xslt, rtf

HI i need to change only the AM/PM to am/pm in this

Date:<format-date:xdoxslt:sysdate_as_xsdformat();'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'>

i had tried to get but how to use Extended SQL and XSL Functions  i read that both XSL and SQL cant be used at the same time.

Comment: If your question is about XSLT, then please provide an example of the XML input, your current XSLT stylesheet and the expected output. Also state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Answer (score 0):

If your processor supports XSLT 2.0 or higher, you could do something like:

```
replace(replace($input, 'AM$', 'am'), 'PM$', 'pm')
```

Otherwise you'll have to output:

```
substring($input, 1, 21)
```

followed by:

```
translate(substring($input, 22), 'AMP', 'amp')
```